# Make image contain IP

Tags: php, image, ip, png, jpeg

I have a PHP script it generates an image with the users IP. I need to upload this to an image host, but they all say `Invalid file type` or something along those lines. I did, however, see this: [[[image: http://www.danasoft.com/sig/novice27b.jpg]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYUPU.png)](http://www.danasoft.com/sig/novice27b.jpg)

and that leads to my question - how can I make a PNG, JPG, etc. image that contains an your IP?

My PHP code:

```
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, get_client_ip(), $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
```

The code works - the uploading by URL does not...

Comment: What is your upload script looking like?

Comment: @Rasclatt I do not know. It is not my upload script.

Comment: You said *"the uploading by URL does not"*, where is that part?

Comment: @Rasclatt I tried using https://postimage.io/ https://imgbb.com/ and a few more

Comment: So you don't have a form on your site to upload an image? That will be required.

Comment: @Rasclatt In order to post my ip-image on a certain forum I need it to be on a certain image host. Those image hosts do not let me upload the php file.